# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String error using BackgroundTimer.setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm using react-native-background-timer getting error android as well as ios while calling function BackgroundTimer.setTimeout

```
useEffect(() => {
    let timeId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(() => {
      BackgroundTimer.start();
      AppContext.UpdateCart([]);
      SecureStorage.setItem("CART", []);
    }, 20 * 60 *1000);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [DOC](https://github.com/oyyq99999/react-native-secure-storage/blob/master/README.md) you shouldn't put an array `[]` as second param for `SecureStorage.setItem`. you may try to put 0-length `String` or `null` as framework expects

```
SecureStorage.setItem("CART", ""); // empty, 0-length string
```

there is also `AppContext.UpdateCart([]);` line, ensure you can put an empty array in here, maybe also in here you should put some `String`

Comment: thanks, buddy. i set 2nd param as empty string in  SecureStorage.setItem. now it's working perfectly fine. -:)

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!